# Django Rest Framework API is being called twice

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using Django Rest Framework to make a custom backend that does the web3 login flow.
However, it is calling my authenticate function twice.
And I can't figure out why.

my token view:

```
#expects public_address, nonce and token if user is currently signed in
@api_view(["POST"])
def get_token(request):
    logger.debug(request.data)
    public_address =  request.data["public_address"]
    web3 = Web3Backend()
    logger.debug(web3)
    logger.debug('running authenticate from token endpoint')
    user, token = web3.authenticate(request)
    logger.debug(user)
    logger.debug(token)
    if token:
        return JsonResponse({'token': token})
    else:
        return Response({'message': 'Missing token'}, status=400)
```

Authenticate Function:

```
def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
    logger.debug(request);
    public_address = request.data.get('public_address', None)
    nonce = request.data.get('nonce', None)
    curr_token = request.data.get('token', None)
    Web3User = get_user_model()
    if public_address:
        if curr_token:
            #TODO: decode token and check if public_address is the same as the user calling it and if not expired
                #TODO: if yes then just return true and token
            token =jwt.decode(curr_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms="HS256")
            #TODO: convert into datetime and make sure the current datetime is not pass this
            expiry = datetime. strptime(token['expiry'],'%y-%m-%d')
            now = datetime.date.today()
            logger.debug(expiry)
            logger.debug(now)
            if(token['user'] == public_address and expiry < now):
                logger.debug('JWT still valid')
                return True, curr_token
            else:
                return AuthenticationFailed()
        #TODO: decode the JWT and check if the user is the proper user
        try:
            #TODO: database check; will want to switch to JWT tokens in the future with refresh check to grab user
            logger.debug('grabbing web3user to authenticate')
            web3user = Web3User.objects.get(public_address=public_address)
            #TODO: check nonce is signed correctly by user's private key by using the public key
            if (web3user and self._check_nonce(web3user, nonce)):
                logger.debug('everything passed')
                #TODO: make JWT expiration in Django server config
                expiry = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                token = jwt.encode({"user": public_address, "expiry": str(expiry) }, SECRET_KEY, algorithm="HS256")
                try:
                    web3user.nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex
                    web3user.save()
                except Ex:
                    #TODO: return an exception response
                    logger.debug(Ex)
                    #TODO: 500 error
                    return NotFound()
                logger.debug(web3user)
                logger.debug(token)
                return web3user, token
            else:
                #TODO: return a 401 unauthorized
                logger.debug('nonce not correct')
                pass
        except Web3User.DoesNotExist:
            #TODO: return an exception response
            logger.debug('user not found')
            return Web3User.DoesNotExist
    else:
        #TODO: return a 204 to signify a user does not exist and have the frontend to send a POST /user request
        logger.debug('no nonce or public_address')
        return None, None
```

My output but I scrubbed my address:

```
Django version 3.2.8, using settings 'Dapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[02/Dec/2021 19:47:05] "GET /api/user/0x50b67302a301d9489b998fa388c2398df9b8c2fb HTTP/1.1" 200 139
<rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/token/'>
grabbing web3user to authenticate
0xMY_ADDRESSS
0xMY_ADDRESSS
True
everything passed
0xMY_ADDRESSS
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiMHg1MGI2NzMwMmEzMDFkOTQ4OWI5OThmYTM4OGMyMzk4ZGY5YjhjMmZiIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoiMjAyMS0xMi0wMyJ9.vfdAktrnSBvhwc11_kkjhX_-Yr7YE8G5dXG0lEfAO0g
{'nonce': '0xd315b6d63a0eef332cdb56b7fdb6e22b3ee238e742df5399ea613b8df681c4cf35f480583ccc8008a803a91418d3155681274ed089b40e6fa02b5ee00de1ccfe1c', 'public_address': '0x50b67302a301d9489b998fa388c2398df9b8c2fb'}
<core.auth.backends.Web3Backend object at 0x7fca6d161760>
running authenticate from token endpoint
<rest_framework.request.Request: POST '/api/token/'>
grabbing web3user to authenticate
0x8598f086842e4486cb35bd4b109054a066f27187
0x50b67302a301d9489b998fa388c2398df9b8c2fb
False
nonce not correct
Internal Server Error: /api/token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/core/auth/views.py", line 25, in get_token
    user, token = web3.authenticate(request)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
Internal Server Error: /api/token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kcelica/Code/Django-for-web3/core/auth/views.py", line 25, in get_token
    user, token = web3.authenticate(request)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Proof my frontend only calls the /token endpoint once:

[image]

Django Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'core',
    'django.contrib.admin',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL='core.Web3User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'core.auth.backends.Web3Backend'
    ]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Dapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Dapp.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: I’m not convinced that your frontend is not calling this token API twice.

Comment: I checked by adding a call in my client right before it makes the request.

Comment: @KeoniGarner posted a picture of my Network tab to show it only calls it once.

Comment: So the token view doesn’t get called twice, it’s just the authenticate function?

Comment: that's my theory cause that's what the console log shows.

Comment: My guess is that you’re using the IsAuthenticated backend globally which checks is_authenticated on the request.user - then you manually authenticate which, obviously calls the function again. Mind sharing your drf settings?

Comment: @KeoniGarner added it to the post!

Comment: Okay so I’m pretty sure I know how this happened, but just to be ultra-sure, can you add your class based view?

Comment: Actually I found it in your other question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply rewriting it as a class-based view called Web3UserToken and creating a post method.
However, I do not know why that fixed it so will leave it up until I have an explanation before crafting a full answer.

I think however maybe the decorator version calls authenticate underneath and so when I was calling /api/token/ it was calling authenticate and then authenticate again in my view.

Comment: So, your hunch was right - the decorator calls your authenticate method. The way the decorator works is it basically creates a Class-Based View with everything set to the default classes including authentication classes. The authentication in DRF works by checking against your configured authentication backends until it finds a match, but it **only checks** when request.user is accessed. Your class based view works around this by setting the authentication_classes to an empty list (something you could also do with the decorator, but it would be using a separate decorator.

Comment: Personally, I think you should stop calling your Web3Backend directly and use DRF authentication, but that’s your prerogative.

Comment: true but I'm kinda stuck on the design pattern to return a token then. and i dont want to store my token in the db - if i did i could just return `user.token` but I'm also following a few other examples of Django Token auth libraries

Comment: Doesn’t simplejwt handle this gracefully? Is that on your list of examples?